# Can a similar crystal and not exactly the one on the datasheet be used on RF 433 receiver?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, rf, radio, 433mhz

The [datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811141751_Synoxo-SYN531R_C77785.pdf) of SYN531R suggests 13.51783 MHz crystal.

I found available available 13.52127 MHz on an online store.

It seems very similar to me, however in reality would it work and if yes, would it make a big difference or not?
Is it of a so big importance the crystal to be exactly the same one as on the datasheet or not?

Comment: What's on the other side (the transmitter)? Is it something you are building as well? This receiver seem to be pretty sensitive to frequency differences.

Comment: On the other side is a transmitter based on SYN115( datasheet: https://www.rhydolabz.com/documents/33/SYN113-SYN115-datasheet-version-1-1-.0.pdf )

Comment: That transmitter is a joke. OBW < 1000kHz. Oh how nice, except the band isn't even 1000kHz wide! Also so funny how these parts list harmonics & emissions always at like -38dBm. With the legal limit being some -37.5dBm. "No, we aren't trashy at all, look, you got several microvolts/m in margin!"

Comment: @Kris Oh, I was just assuming you might want to use this radio legally in Europe, North Africa, Middle-East, Australia or South America. If you only intend to use it in some exotic country I know nothing about, then OOK away by all means.

Comment: @Lundin yes I do. As i replied to you on your answer(thanks for your time) synoxo is a european company so I do not understand why you say its illegal to use those components...

Comment: *you say its illegal to use those components* It is illegal to **transmit at frequencies where you are not allowed to do so**. If you use the SYN115 with the wrong crystal, you could be transmitting at a frequency where it is illegal to transmit. These chips can be used but you must use them **properly**, meaning at the correct frequency.

Answer (score 2):

In the datasheet there's this formula:

Fosc = Frf / (32 + 1.198/12)

OFFICIAL QUARTZ CRYSTAL:

When using the official quartz crystal you get a carrier frequency of 433.92 Mz

13.51783 MHz = (433.92 / (32 + 1.198/12))  MHz

UNOFFICIAL QUARTZ CRYSTAL:

When using the unofficial quartz crystal you get a carrier frequency of 433,9967 MHz

You are off of by 70 KHz and the receiver might go blind.

Comment: *the incoming signal is usually 25 KHz or less, for this kind of receivers, by law.* What law? I can receive all I want as long as my **transmissions** stay within the allowed frequencies and power. The SYN531 has an IF bandwidth of 330 kHz (page 3 of the datasheet), for receiving OOK signals that will work fine.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The law is called EU 2006/771/EC unless national law is different, then national law takes precedence. For 434.04-434.79 EU-wide, you either need to keep 10mW ERP 10% duty cycle, or 1mW ERP 13 dBm/10 kHz power density for bandwidth modulation larger than 250 kHz, or 10mW ERP 25kHz channel spacing. Channel spacing applies to the receiver as well as the transmitter.

Comment: In either of the three cases, I don't see how 1MHz occupied band 10mW ERP fits the bill.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual that you linked: `F OSC = F RF /(32 + 1.198/12)`. This is the ref oscillator they expect. And yes it will make a huge difference which one you pick because this oscillator determines how stable your frequency is. Professional radio designs will use a TCXO here. Depending on the transmitter, you don't necessarily have to place your carrier on 433.92MHz however. Use the formula they gave you and see if you end up within the license free radio band.

However, the part you linked is highly problematic to use on the 433MHz band, where ASK and OOK simply aren't feasible due to the high amount of other radios present on that band.  Sensitivity and image rejection are mediocre. Always avoid parts that don't list adjacent channel sensitivity/rejection, because that always means it's poor. The IF bandwidth of 330kHz also makes it useless in practice. This is a skunky part and I don't see how you can design a legal, working radio with it, at least not if you intend to use it in Europe.

Comment: which part is problematic? receiver or transmitter? Synoxo is a european company so i guess its not illegal.. what makes it illegal?

Comment: @Kris The 433MHz band differs a bit from country to country in Europe. EU has tried to standardize it and they divide the band in two: one from 433.050 to 434.900 where you are only allowed 1mW ERP or 10mW ERP with 10% duty cycle. Alternatively you can use 434.040 - 434.900 with 10mW ERP. Typically you need to be narrowband <25kHz. At the very least you need to fit inside the f***n' band, which rules out OCB of 1MHz. ->

Comment: @Kris But in either case, your radio needs to be legal. That means non-specified short range device (SRD) conforming to EN 300 220-2 under the RED directive. This standard doesn't take kindly to wide band crap nor spurious emissions. The limit of some -37dBm comes from this standard and just so it happens your linked transmitter spews out noise just above this limit, what a coincidence! I believe harmonics have tougher requirements of some -50dBm, I don't remember.

Comment: *Typically you need to be narrowband <25kHz* Realize that this is the **receiver**. I agree that a narrow band and matching the frequency at which the transmitter is transmitting is "better" but as long as this (wideband) receiver can receive the signal, the system can work.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I'm referring to the linked transmitter in comments below the question.

Comment: thank you for your info. So you are saying that IF bandwidth has to be <25kHz and it is 330KHz(receiver)..and that makes it "illegal" ?

Comment: I agree that the **transmitter** must be transmitting in the frequency band that is allowed. You do make it sound as if these ICs are very poor. I agree they're quite cheap and their range isn't great (50 meter?) but they do work. You do have to use them with the correct crystals. OP: On Ebay you can buy ready-made modules including the correct crystal, why not use those? I do and they work fine.

Comment: @Kris IF has nothing to do with it, the 25kHz carrier channel bandwidth is the band requirement in most countries. It just means that the IF is wide band and generally low quality. Which makes sense if you only intend OOK. Which isn't feasible for quality reasons. Except the average city to be cluttered with 433MHz transmitters here and there.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie What license band on allows 1MHz occupied band with 10mW ERP? The out of band emissions will likely be all over the place too.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I "copied" their schematics on my custom PCB. Lundin I understand your thoughts of those chips being cheap and not good quality etc but still I did not understand what makes them "illegal". Low powered devices(short range) as far as I know(or I thought I knew) do not require any license etc. If you could please explain in plain English what makes it illegal

Comment: @Kris In plain English: you are allowed to drive on the public highway if you have a drivers license and an inspected car. You are however not allowed to drive a monster truck without plates, far wider than the whole highway, it's wheels tearing up all public property on the sides of the highway. You also end up blocking the highway for everyone else, so they get very annoyed at you. And as soon as any little car happens to drive in front of you, you have to wait for them to leave the highway, since your massive monster truck is so easy to block.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now what makes the transmitter and receiver that I chose illegal? 1. 2. 3. if you could please state all those things that make them illegal, it would help me to choose a more suitable ones.

Comment: Is it only the <1000kHz bandwidth that makes it illegal? If you see on the notes 6. "RBW = 100kHz OBW measured at -20dBc" thanks for your info!

Comment: @Kris They aren't illegal but they can't very well be used to design a legal radio operating on the 433MHz band in Europe. You can read about the band restrictions from the government radio authorities per country. Some countries in Europe have more lenient local rules, including Germany, France, Sweden, Netherlands and probably a few others. In either case, your radio must conform to EN ETSI 300 220 v3.1.1. It's available for free [here](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/300200_300299/30022001/03.01.01_30/en_30022001v030101v.pdf)

Comment: @Kris EU-wide though, there's the directive 2006/771/EC which is an attempt of standardization. There you have the already mentioned requirements.

Comment: @Lundin thank you for your inputs. I might jump to a reputable company like TI CC1101 ( https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1101.pdf ) to be on the safe side!

Comment: @Kris Rather, you should download ETSI 300 220, see what parts that may apply to your product and ask a question here if you don't understand certain parts. If your product conforms to 300 220 you can sell it pretty much any country that has a license-free 433MHz band.

Comment: My remarks about ASK and OOK being unsuitable has nothing to do with legislation though, I just know from experience that they simply won't work on this band. For example Volvo cars made a simple wideband 433MHz radio for their car keys at one point, with some questionable modulation method. Then everyone who happened to own a Volvo often couldn't lock or unlock their car in case they happened to use their car in a city. In cities, other transmitters will be present.

Comment: Switching to 868MHz I would have less penetration capability though. If I use CC1101 transceiver which supports 2FSK and 4FSK, would it be more suitable? Leave the legislation aside at the moment, talking about suitability. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Kris 868 has the same issues as 433. FSK modulation means that you can use narrowband FM, which makes a huge difference. It's far more rugged than ASK or OOK. Unrelated to that, given the shortage of semiconductors in general at the moment, check that the parts are actually available before you pick a design.

Comment: @Lundin in FSK(2FSK and 4FSK), the data are transmitted on different frequencies-channels or on 1 channel and +- bit of frequency deviation? The first one is probably the hopping but just to make sure I understand correctly how FSK works. Also every bit in FSK goes through different frequency or all the data are transmitted to the base frequency and to other frequencies arround the base +- some deviation

Comment: @Kris You have a carrier at a certain frequency and then modulation going +/- that frequency, depending on method. I'm not the right person to explain the various FSK variants in detail. The best is to look at spectrum examples showing how the modulated signal will look. Anyway, this is drifting far off-topic.